# use multiple inbuilt functions in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
    if($("#framework option[value='UnSelect-All']").is(':selected'))
  {
     unselectAll();
  }
```

For the above condition, I need to check for is not selected
something like

```
.is().not((':selected'))
```

Comment: You can negate the expression by placing a bang before the selector: `if(!$("#framework option[value='UnSelect-All']").is(':selected'))`

Comment: `.is(':not(:selected)')` or `.not(':selected')`

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you can do that :

1. You can put `! $("#framework option[value='UnSelect-All']:selected")`.
2. You can use `! $("#framework option[value='UnSelect-All']").is(":selected")`.
3. You can use `$("#framework option[value='UnSelect-All']").not(":selected")`

There are many other ways as well.